# How can I add my Facebook friends to my Battle.net contacts in Diablo III?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

In *Starcraft II* you can have it [flip through your Facebook friends](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/real-id#q4) and add people that have the game to your Battle.net friends list.  How do you do this in *Diablo III*?

Answer (score 6):

Diablo 3 hasn't implemented it yet. But if you have Starcraft 2, go on that and browse your facebook friends, add them, and when they accept it will show up on your Diablo 3 friends list.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to browse your Facebook friendlist in Diablo 3. You have to add them manually via their email-address or battle-tag: Click on the friend list button to the lower right, then click on "add friend" and type in your friends data.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't available in Diablo III.  The only options for adding a friend are their Real ID and their battle tag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the above recommendation to add them in Starcraft II is the best way, if you have it that is. Because I'm pretty sure it's pulling the friends from their Bttle.net account and not from Starcraft II specifically so if they're on Battle.net, for Diablo III or otherwise, this will work.

My Starcraft II picked up my brother who only created a Battle.net account for a Diablo III guest pass and doesn't own Starcraft II.