# Is it possible to manage Battle.net friends out of game?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

I just started playing Diablo III and have noticed that, so far, I've only been able to add friends and accept friend requests from in-game.  This is a bit frustrating, as I usually chat to my mates during lunchtime - a perfect time to manage my friends list online.

Is there a way to do this?  I've looked through the [battle.net site](http://eu.battle.net/en/) and the [Diablo III community site](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/community/) and, if the option is there somewhere, it's certainly not obvious!

Does anyone know if this is a feature that is planned?

PS I already noticed that there's no Facebook import feature in D3: [How can I add my Facebook friends to my Battle.net contacts in Diablo III?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66545/how-can-i-add-my-facebook-friends-to-my-battle-net-contacts-in-diablo-iii)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's currently no way to add or manage friends other than [via the in-game client](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battletagfaq#q12).

However, since BattleTag friends are shared with SC2 BattleTag friends, you can see a list of your friends if you visit [your SC2 friends page](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/friends) (assuming, of course, that you and your friend both have SC2).

Your SC2 friends page should be at `http://<"eu"/"us"/etc.>.battle.net/sc2/<"en"/etc.>/profile/friends` (e.g. http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/friends if you're logged in to your EU SC2 account on Battle.net).

Comment: Oak, my good fellow, your second link seems to be broken.

Comment: @LordScree Thanks old chap, I think it should be better now!

Comment: Haha, I'm afraid not, but I get the picture - perhaps the link is only available if you've already logged in or something.

Comment: It is indeed only working if you are logged in. However you can go to the link, log in and you will be redirected back to the working page.

Comment: It's now 2017 and I can't believe there is **still** no way to manage friends for the _Blizzard Entertainment Battle.net_ account online or via a smartphone app.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [real id faq](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/real-id#q1) you can only add friends in-game.

Answer (score 3):

[Battle.net Desktop App](https://us.battle.net/app/) now support chating with friends and you can add new

Answer (score -3):

Finally a thing! As of Sep 26th 2017.

Comment: Adding some more information, such as a brief overview of some of the new features, would make this answer much better.